# list on the right of a left floating image

Tags: css, image, list

I want to properly position an ul list on the right of a left-floating img using outside list property, but the bullets aren't aligned on the right of the image, as where there isn't any image, but more on the left.

```
<img style="float: left; margin-right: 0.1em;" src="http://commons.cathopedia.org/w/images/commons/thumb/f/fe/Carnevale_di_Venezia.JPG/250px-Carnevale_di_Venezia.JPG" />
<ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cnsectetur cnsecteturcnsectetur um dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
</ul>
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2z6Zn/31/) for a better understanding.

I cannot modify html, only css.

I don't want to put the list property to inside.

If I add a right margin to the image, the not-ul text is moved too, and I don't want it.

If I add a left margin or padding to ul or li, the lists which aren't on the right of an image are moved inward too, and I don't want it.

How do I manage it?

Comment: keep them in different div's...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try with adding overflow hidden in ul tag http://jsfiddle.net/2z6Zn/61/:

```
ul {
    padding-left: 1.2em;
    overflow: hidden;
}​
```

Comment: reading [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) I don't understand how the "overflow: hidden" property work in this case. Could you explain me o give me a hint? thank you!

Comment: float on image push only contents in ul element but not the whole ul, it takes 100% available space as a block level element. you can verify it by inspect element. Thats why left margins are not working on ul. This is not a bug, you can see more details here: http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=57882. Overflow hidden ensures to hide empty area of ul

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sriganesh/2z6Zn/32/)

Is that you looking for? I am not sure.... Check this and explain more if you need to add more...

```
img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.9em;
     position: relative;
}

li {
    list-style-position: outside;
}
ul {
    padding-left: 1.2em;
}​
```

Comment: No, I need to get, at the right of the image, the bullet aligned with the <p> text.

Comment: Updated answer... Is that you looking for?

Comment: Explain once again, how would you want? Thanks